# After uploading, how can I reorganize my files on Ubuntu One cloud storage using a Mac?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac

For example, I uploaded  13 files, now I want to put them in a folder for better organization. Right now I cannot see a way to move files around once uploaded. I would hate to have to reupload all my files again just to put them in folders.

I am using a Mac.

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the web interface does not provide a way to move files.

If you need to do this from a Mac, you could try using the [u1ftp](https://launchpad.net/u1ftp) API demonstration program I wrote, which lets you manage your files through a stub FTP server running locally.

Simply download the ZIP file from https://launchpad.net/u1ftp and run the following from the terminal:

```
python u1ftp-0.1.zip
```

Now use an FTP client to connect to `localhost` on port `2121` using your Ubuntu One credentials.  Performing moves or renames should happen fully server side, and avoid re-uploading the files.

While MacOS's Finder has some FTP capabilities, it only supports read-only operations so is not suitable for this job.  Pretty much any of the dedicated FTP clients should do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-organise the files in to new folders,  using nautilus file manager on your computer.
(inside your ubuntu one or other synced folders)

They will then be re-synced to reflect the location changes on ubuntu one.
Only the new folders will be uploaded.

Comment: I am on a Mac and I know there is no desktop software available. With that said, am I going to have to re-upload if I want to organize?

Comment: To be honest I don't know as I don't have a Mac. I have edited your question to include this information, changes should appear shortly & someone with more experience of Mac's should answer. Sorry not to be of more help. :o(